# Audio format to choose for Big audio files

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

Which audio file format is best to use for large audio files? I have many large audio files to be used in my app but their current mp3 size is of hundred of MB's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save more storage on audio files, file format may not change too much on the file size, reducing the bit rate(for example 320Kbps to 128Kbps) can reduce the file size significantly.

Answer (score -1):

:how to do it using microsoft`s audio compression manager?(practically it`s not well documented in m.s.d.n.

Windows provide codecs that compress specifically audio files. The audio files tipically are PCM format (WAVE_FORMAT_PCM) and get played by using the simplest directsound method (check msdn it`s at hand and it works)

To play a file using directsound, thus PCM format you first create a directsound object, create a directsoundbuffer, and then pump the PCM data directly to the buffer using a keep-fill-buffer algorithm.

If you wish to use codecs, u try and write a procedure that opens a *stream* file and passes it through a acm driver object, thus (de)compressing it.

The driver for ACM (audio compression manager) finds a codecs that suits the input source and decompresses it yet again to WAVE_FORMAT_PCM for your app be able to play it.